# Solve generating function for $a_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am not sure how to solve questions like this. I am aware of both recurrence relations and generating functions and how two of these concepts work, but I find it hard to combine them. I would really appreciate if you could explain how to solve it. Thank you!

Three standard six-sided dice are thrown. Write down a closed-form expression for the generating function for $a_n$, the number of ways in which a total of n can be thrown using the three dice, assuming that the dice are distinguishable. You should express the function as compactly as possible, but are not required to identify the coefficients in power series expansion.

Comment: General recipes are given by the [theory of species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species), but that is too much for this problem. Consider the generating function $1+x+x^2+...+x^6$, When you multiply the right hand side by itself $6$ times, how do you distribute and collected terms of the same degree? To get a term of degree $n$ we choose $x^{a_1}$ from the first factor, $x^{a_2}$ from the second,..., $x^{a_6}$ from the last such that $a_1+a_2+...+a_6=n$. The coefficient will count in how many ways this can be done.

Comment: Your problem statement does not match your title.  The problem statement asks you to find the generating function but does not require you to find an expression for $a_n$.